# How can I record a macro in excel that resizes my chart?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I start to record the macro, then I click on my chart, I resize it then I finish recording. The problem is that this recorded macro will only work on that specific chart that I selected during the recording.

Is there a way to record a macro that works on any selected chart? Excel writes this code:

```
Sub resize()
'
' resize Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 6").Height = 256.5354330709
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagram 6").Width = 405.3543307087
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Select** the shape or chart and run this:

```
Sub resize()
    Selection.Height = 256.5354330709
    Selection.Width = 405.3543307087
End Sub
```